# How use shortkey as variable instead text

Tags: autohotkey

Here my code:

```
key0 = {1}
key1 = {A}

Loop
{
    If (GetKeyState(key0, "P"))
    {
        Send {key1}
    }
    else
    {
        Send {key0}
    }

    sleep 500
}

F12::ExitApp
```

Not works correctly. Cannot use keys as variables. Can anyone explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax in the send command would be with `%` sign around the variable. Also you have figure brace in declaration `{A}` - should be just `A` if you use `{A}` literal, then it is not possible to do e.g. `{a down}`. 
E.g. you pass `key0` to `Getkeystate()` - the first argument there must be just key name unlike the curly braces in the `send` command.

Try this:

```
key0 = 1
key1 = A
loop
{
    if getkeystate(key0, "P")
    {
        send {%key1%}
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I just need to declare the key. The Send command can send text or a key. I need a second. In my example, {A} is a button with the letter A. I may need such a record {<! + A}, or {# ^ 4}. GetKeyState("b", "P") Your example does not suit me

Comment: Thanks. But your example send A as text not as Key, And Games not react

Comment: @nim try `sc01E` instead of `A` then it should work. But the results may depend on the application. If you just want to rebind something better use hotkeys, not loops with getkeystate - you may run into many difficulties.  Games can use different event polling approaches. I recommend asking on Autohotkey forum for specific  game and what you re trying to achieve.